# Three.js Updating mesh of TubeGeometry object

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to create an tube and ability to interact with that tube like dragging mouse to change the start point/end point of the tube .For that I modify directly vertices position values and I would like update object in the scene

However, I've struck a problem with the tube object I'm using: when I update the path points the mesh object doesn't update on the screen, so it seems like I can't modify it after it's been created.

My 3d object creation is roughly like this:

```
var curve = new THREE.SplineCurve3([new THREE.Vector3(x, y, z), new THREE.Vector3(x2, y2, z2)]);
var geometry = new THREE.TubeGeometry(curve, segments, 2, radiusSegments, closed);
geometry.dynamic = true;
var tubeMesh = THREE.SceneUtils.createMultiMaterialObject(geometry, [new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({color: 0xffffff, opacity: 1, transparent: true})]);
scene.add(tubeMesh);
```

And when I want to update the points. I'm doing it like this:

```
tubeMesh.children[0].geometry.path.points[0] = new THREE.Vector3(x4, y4, z4));
tubeMesh.children[0].geometry.path.points[1] = new THREE.Vector3(x3, y3, z3));
tubeMesh.children[0].geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

However, when I make changes the object doesn't seem to update on screen. Is it possible to do this with a Tube?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have only provided code fragments, but you probably need

```
geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
```

and

```
geometry.dynamic = true;
```

You can find more detail and examples in the Three.js wiki about how to update things with `WebGLRenderer`.

https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/wiki/Updates

Comment: I did read that article before and in my code above also included the code you mentioned. Seem that the verticeNeedUpdate only applied when the vertices property is changed. While here I'm changing the path property of the geo. The guys here have the same problem like me https://github.com/mrdoob/three.js/issues/1965

Comment: How about creating a simple jsfiddle?

Comment: I created one here: http://jsfiddle.net/drsagitn/dC5KA/2/ .The points are updated on mouseup event. Thanks.

Comment: Here is a working fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/kWw68/3/. The extruded path is only used to construct the geometry. You have to update the mesh geometry itself, not the path. (Naming the path `tube` caused some of the confusion.) I _hope_ you can accept this as an answer to your question.

Comment: Thank you very much for the jsfiddle. It's true that this is a way to update the Tube but I think it wont be practical for users. As when user needs update, he would like to update the path points rather than looping through all the vertices and calculating new position for each. So in this case, I may need to re-create the the mesh with new geometry?

Comment: Yes, it is probably best to re-create the mesh with a new geometry.